# DirectX9 CreateDeviceEx fails with D3DERR_NOTAVAILABLE

Tags: windows, graphics, directx

On creating and destroying DirectX9 device repeatedly after some time the CreateDeviceEx call fails *randomly* with the error : **0x8876086A (D3DERR_NOTAVAILABLE)**

On enabling Debug spew on debug directX binaries, I see the following log when the CreateDeviceEx call fails :

> **Direct3D9: (ERROR) : DDraw and Direct3D are not supported in less than 8bpp modes. Creating Device fails.**

Moreover, if it helps, I get this error only on laptop, not on my desktop computer running on similar configuration.

Any clue as to what maybe going wrong ?

I am using latest Windows 10 release and GTX-980 (desktop) / GTX-1060 (Laptop) with latest graphics drivers.

As Requested, following are the D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS :

```
D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;
d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = 128;
d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = 128;
d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
d3dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = TRUE;
d3dpp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D16;
d3dpp.PresentationInterval = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_IMMEDIATE;
```

Comment: Perhaps post your code, particularly, the `D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS` you're passing into `CreateDeviceEx`?

Comment: @MuertoExcobito following is the CreateDeviceEx call : 
CreateDeviceEx(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT
                      , D3DDEVTYPE_HAL
                      , hWnd
                      , D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING | D3DCREATE_MULTITHREADED
                      , &d3dpp
                      , NULL
                      , &pD3DDev);